# How can I configure metric alerts for a SQL Azure Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to configure an alert on the 'CPU Percentage' metric of my SQL Azure database. Since the classic Alerts functionality of Azure will be retired soon, I am trynig the new Alerts experience:
[image]

However, when I select my database and then try to define the alert criteria, it shows no metric signals at all, only Activity Log signals. Am I doing something wrong here, or is it just not possible anymore in the new Azure Alerts functionality?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PowerShell to create an alert for DTU consumption:

```
$ResourceGroup = 'IntroAzureSql'
$location = 'West US'
$server = 'msf-sqldb'
$db = 'MSFADMIN'
$rid = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ResourceName &quot;$server/$db&quot;).ResourceID
$email = New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -CustomEmails 'mfal@dummy.com' -SendToServiceOwners
Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule -Name 'DTU90Check' <code>
-Location $location </code>
-ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup <code>
-TargetResourceId $rid </code>
-MetricName 'dtu_consumption_percent' <code>
-Operator GreaterThanOrEqual </code>
-Threshold 90 <code>
-WindowSize '00:05:00' </code>
-TimeAggregationOperator Maximum `
-Actions $email
```

For more information, please read [this](http://www.mikefal.net/2016/08/23/creating-alerts-for-azure-sql-database-with-powershell/) article.

Comment: Almost right... I was asking for CPU Percentage, but the linked article helped me to the answer. `Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule -Name 'Percentage CPU Greater than 80' -Location 'West Europe' -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup -TargetResourceId $rid -MetricName 'cpu_percent' -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 80 -WindowSize '00:05:00' -TimeAggregationOperator Average -Actions $email`. Please update your answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm glad for you!

Comment: @EdwindeKoning screenshot you have in the question is from new alert (Azure Monitor--> alert). Creating the same using `Add-AzMetricAlertRule` or `Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule` with old module still create the alert under classic. Is that what you are seeing and how did you get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Next generation metrics/alert for Azure SQL has not yet been published so you only have "Classic" at this moment. It will go live during 2019 so just keep an eye out for when it arrives.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-insights-alerts-portal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just followed up with a team in charge of this. Once new alerts are available (in 2019), all existing classic alerts should be automatically migrated from the old classic into the new alerting system with no user action required.

The team will also look into removing this generic message from the alerts section for SQL Database as no action is needed.

Thank you once again on your feedback, appreciate it.

-Dani

Azure SQL Database